# C# Tracing Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

1. I have developed a website using asp.net and c#.
2. I published that website using visual studio.
3. I gave that published website to my customers( more than 100).
4. My customers configured it in their own website.

I have handled exceptions using try catch and write log file in (c:\Log\Log.txt) with unique id and datetime.
My problem is whenever any exception occurs for my clients, to solve the issue  i need that log.txt file. But i have to wait till they provide log.txt file.

So , is there any way to read that exception using any code or any tool?.(now i cant modify my source because of customers currently running it).

For example: i give customer's URL in browser and performing some operations.Now i need a tool or code that should trace exceptions while i am accessing that website

Comment: Coincidentally, that's called "tracing". What have you tried?

Comment: Aren't you a little late with this? You made some logging framework, but forgot to put the crucial point in, and now you want to fix it without fixing the code? How do you want to gain access to the customer machines?

Comment: Instead of saving it in log-file? why not you mail the stack trace to your email from application?

Comment: I tried using fiddler and debug view tools but i unable to trace the exceptions.

Comment: yes good idea. But i didnt implemented that while developing. for feature i may try it. But for present i cant.

Comment: Try to use `Trace` . here is the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82290/Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Trace-the-ASP-NET-Applicatio) which will guide you to learn it

Comment: you can create a service which checks the log file after regular interval and if it founds any changes in it, it will send you the mail. (or if your logfile can be at any shared location) you can install that service on some other machine and check the log file at regular interval

Comment: You can use file watcher base windows service.

Comment: Prashant Mehta: Thanks. Kindly provide any link. I dont aware of file watcher.

Comment: Patrick Hofman : Yes you are correct. But its fine if there any solution for this. Without access customer machine, like fiddler or debug view tool we can do something. Or simply any code to fetch that exception alone from browser. From browser only that exception will save to notepad. So kindly tell to catch that exception if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After search in google i found that its not possible to trace exceptions on a website without modifying its code. Even using tools such as fiddler we can find only web requests and response.